# Why is Haskell complaining about this plus sign?

Tags: haskell

From this code intended to convert a balanced ternary representation to a Haskell `Integer`:

```
frombal3 :: String -> Integer
frombal3 "+" =  1
frombal3 "0" =  0
frombal3 "-" = -1
frombal3 current:therest = \
  (*) frombal3 current (^) 3 length therest \
  + frombal3 therest
```

I got the error:

```
main.hs:7:3: error: parse error on input ‘+’
  |
7 |   + frombal3 therest
  |   ^
<interactive>:3:1: error:
   • Variable not in scope: main
   • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: Don't use a backslash to continue a line. Haskell just requires indentation.

Comment: Side question: How come you're using prefix operators? I would think it's easiest to use operators between numbers, as they're supposed to be used. Besides, your program gives several type errors when you do fix the parse errors; these would probably go away when you get rid of the prefix operators (or at least parenthesise them).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but I can see some mistakes that can be already pointed out.

## Problems

You don't need `\` to continue a line, that's only needed inside strings. Indentation is enough in Haskell

You need to wrap your pattern matching with parenthesis: `(current:therest)`. Furthermore, this pattern will make `current` a Char and not a String, so you cannot directly pass it to your function that takes a String.

You need to wrap your function arguments as well: if you want to multiply `frombal3 current` by 3, you need `(*) (frombal3 current) 3`, or the much better `frombal3 current * 3`. Infix functions have higher precedence and make the code more clear.

## Suggestions

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but this looks like somthing that can be done with a `fold` or simple list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Don't use backslashes, and remember to properly bracket pattern matches:

```
frombal3 :: String -> Integer
frombal3 "+" =  1
frombal3 "0" =  0
frombal3 "-" = -1
frombal3 (current:therest) = -- ^ Note brackets
  (*) frombal3 current (^) 3 length therest 
  + frombal3 therest
```

This still causes a problem due to how you're using operators, but I think you can solve this on your own, especially since I can't work out what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to use backslashes to continue onto the next line; don't do that. If you just delete all the backslashes, the error will go away. (You'll get several *other* errors, but this particular one will go away.)

Haskell uses indentation to detect where one part ends and the next begins. You don't need to manually add backslashes to the end of each line to continue an expression.